# POSTMAN - post request giving "The request entity's media type 'application/json' is not supported for this resource."

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Web API code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("GetCMMAutoForLoggedInUser")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCMMAutoForLoggedInUser(CMMPermissionRequest request)
{
    var data = this.CommonDomain.GetCMMAutoForLoggedInUser(request);

    return Ok(data);
}
```

in body I'm specifying below JSON:

```
{ "EnterPriseId": "prasad.kiran.shigwan",
"LocationLevelId": "5",
"LocationLevelValue": "SZ"
}
```

but getting below exception in POSTMAN tool:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The request entity's media type 'application/json' is not supported for this resource.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'CMMPermissionRequest' from content with media type 'application/json'.",
            "type": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
            "stacktrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync\[T\](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
        }
    }
}
```

Refer below screenshot for json from POSTMAN:

[image]

Comment: Does the server at the other end support json - or is it xml or something?

Comment: Keep in mind that when you select `JSON(application/json)` from the dropdown, POSTMAN automatically creates a header for you(`Content-Type:application/json`)

Comment: @Andez yes it support json.

Comment: A couple of things: 1) **Content-Type** really only applies to POST because it describes what you are *sending* to the API; 2) For GET requests, you should set the **Accept** header to **application/json** to tell the API you want JSON returned. ASP.NET WebApi supports JSON unless you have changed the contents of the `config.Formatters` collection in your `WebApiConfig.Register` method.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net Web API has several built-in media type formatters, which are responsible for serializing/deserializing body content from json, xml, etc.

JSON formatter is always on by default, both for ASP.Net Web API 2 and ASP.Net Core Web API. The POST from the question works fine for me for default ASP.Net Web API project, however I can reproduce your problem if remove JSON formatter in `WebApiConfig.Register`:

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

Seems like you have similar code in Web API configuration that unregisters `JsonFormatter`. If this is not the case, set breakpoint in `WebApiConfig.Register` and check what are the values inside `config.Formatters` collection. Here is default list with `JsonFormatter`:

[image]

If for some reason `JsonFormatter` will be missing in your case, you could register it explicitly:

```
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```